# Confusion between memory size/width and register width

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning Assembly language, and we are following the IA-32 architecture. I have a bit of confusion between the terms "register width" and memory size. In the first lecture, we were taught that during our course of the study, we would consider the "width of a register to be of 32 bits(4 bytes)". Then, in the next lecture we are learning about data types, and as an example we were told that if an integer 5(4 bytes) is to be stored, then each byte will go to one memory address space, so by that logic, the storage of the int 5 will span four memory addresses (0-3 so to say). Am I correct in my thinking? Or have I got the concept wrong somewhere? Correct me because making a distinction between the terms "register width" and "memory address" has been confusing me for a while. Thank You!!

Comment: You're correct, if a 32bit register, such as `EAX`  keeps the integer with value **5**, its four bytes will be stored to four bytes in memory. When you reserved the memory and gave it a label, e.g. `MyMem DD 0`, the number **5** will be stored by instruction `MOV [MyMem], EAX` in bytes addressed as `MyMem+0`, `MyMem+1`, `MyMem+2`, `MyMem+3`.  The last three bytes in memory will be zeroes, because IA-32 is *little endian*.

Answer (score 1):

Most processors memory is "byte addressable" meaning the address that we talk about and use as pointers, etc, specifies a specific byte in memory (not going to get into virtual vs physical, just roll with it).  This does not in any way mean that memory is constructed and addressed as bytes.  Often, certainly in a 32 bit x86 processor the buses that can carry memory will be minimum 32 bits but probably larger.  The srams used for cache are certainly not going to be byte addressable from an sram perspective.

How it works if you choose to do a byte access is that for a read, let's say everything is 32 bits wide (the buses, the cache sram, the dram interface, etc) and you want to read some address say 0x1001, what will happen is the 32 bits starting at address 0x1000 (from a byte addressable perspective 0x1000, 0x1001, 0x1002 and 0x1003), and the next to the least significant byte (0x0000XX00) will get extracted usually at the processor not at the memory end of things.

For a write, the bus is 32 bits in this example so you pretty much have to put something there (or let it go high-z but I doubt it), so some garbage will go out on the bus, possibly predictable if you know the processor (stale data from some latch somewhere in the bus interface), so same deal I want to write 0x1001, so based on the bus rules, there will be at least one byte on the bus that is the byte to be written, and some control signals on the bus that indicate this is a single byte write and which byte and address.

Then as you hit these 32 bit (for this example) wide SRAMs and DRAM modules, a read-modify-write happens (in the cache one would hope) so a full 32 bit value is read, the one byte is modified and the 32 bit value is written back (ideally to the SRAM in a cache). Then ideally when the cache flushes the cache line that contained that byte, those writes happen in multiples of this width we have chosen, 32 bits.

Assuming you understood that, the reality is there are multiple buses, multiple caches, and many dram modules you can buy as well as several generations of 32 bit x86 processors (and if you add in all others arm, mips, etc, just multiplies the different implementations).  No reason to assume any two buses on the same system
are the same width, pretty good reason to assume that they are a minimum of 32 bits wide, but likely a multiple of 32 or 64.  Each of the SRAMs are going to be some multiple of 32 bits probably if not 64. So for every access smaller than the width of that sram a read-modify-write has to happen.  Even if say you have a 32 bit x86 processor but the bus is 64 bits the sram is 64 bits, a 32 bit transfer, 16 bit as well as 8 generates a read-modify-write somewhere.

DRAM if you look at modules you can buy, you may see some with 9 parts on one side or on each side.  Or 4 parts or 5 parts, etc.  As time passes for a technology you often see 8 bit wide dram parts and you would put 8 or 9 down depending on if there is ECC support or not (or 16 or 18 if it is dual rank, parts on both sides).  But then might see 4 16 bit wide parts or 2 32 bit wide parts.  Even though you might have 8 bit wide parts on the dram bus, it is very unlikely that they are accessing a byte at a time even though they possibly could.

DRAM being relatively quite slow you want to have a cache out front and want to have transfers to and from dram to be in multiples of the bus width per transfer.  So you want cache lines as such and srams being sized to match in some way to make that side perform well.  And use the cache/sram for read-modify-writes as needed.  Although it is quite possible a byte write could cause a full cache line fetch from dram, then the read-modify-writes in the cache, and that fetch could have caused a flush of some other cache line.  It happens.

Notice not one mention of registers.  Because as far as the memory side goes, the two things are not remotely related.  Registers are registers.  The memory system is the memory system.  Instructions are instructions and connect the two.  Generically the architecture (arm, mips, x86, etc) determines how you use registers to define an address, it defines the addressable range, etc (not uncommon for the address space to be larger than the number of bits in a general purpose register, segment/offset in the early x86 days).

Then per the rules of the INSTRUCTION SET, not registers, is determined if and how you create byte, 16 bit, 32bit, 64 bit, etc transfers to/from registers.  The processor does its magic to deal with processor core stuff then the chip folks deal with on chip stuff if any, then someone deals with the layers of buses/chips between the processor core and the furthest dram or peripheral. Endianness and other topics are covered here.

So a 32 bit write to memory at address 0x1000 is considered a 32 bit write at 0x1000, but also from a byte addressing perspective those four bytes live at 0x1000, 0x1001, 0x1002, 0x1003. They coexist but have to do with read/write transfers not registers not memory, but the rules/definitions for the address space and data per the instruction set.  In a current processor it does not take your 32 bit write and turn it into 4 8 bit writes at the four addresses.  It is one write at the one address.

If later you do a 16 bit read at 0x1000 then that is a 16 bit read at 0x1000.  If you then do two 8 bit reads at 0x1000 and 0x1001 it is the same two bytes as the 16 bit read and half of the bytes from the 32 bit write, it is just a matter of addressing per the instruction set rules.  What happens on the bus, and what happens in the actual memories may or may not have any clue as to the instruction set or transfer size, it follows the bus and logic rules.  The memory system doesn't know what an instruction is, much less care about which architecture, it is designed to do transfers of various sizes.

Which byte of the 16 bit view or 32 bit view is at address 0x1000 is per the rules of the instruction set and some instruction sets have the ability to change on the fly or globally (can switch between big and little endian, and note there is more than one definition for big endian).  Talking generically not specifically x86.  X86 is little endian so the definition is well known.  a write of 0x11223344 to 0x1000, if you read back a byte at 0x1001 then you get 0x33.